# How can I determine the aspect of a participle clause like this "A person parking a car in an illegal place will be arrested."

Tags: participles, aspect

> (1)A person parking a car in an illegal place will be arrested.

Which is true, (A) or (B)? How can I determine the aspect of participle clause like this.

> (A) The rule (1) applies only to those who habitually parks a car in an illegal place

> (B) The rule (1) applies to those who has parked a car in an illegal place even only once.

I have found similar sentences in COCA in which relative clauses are used instead of participle clauses. Can I paraphrase (1) using **who parks** in place of **parking**?

> (2) Making interlopers pay is " a good idea, " said Jason Hogan, an Atlanta Fire Department worker who was taking the train at Arts Center and **who parks at other MARTA lots** a few times a year.

This is clearly "habitual", judging from **a few times a year**

> (3) The rare human being **who parks his car by the road** and makes his way down to the water may find a turtle on the banks or a nest of egrets under the bridge.

This is perhaps "only once".

Comment: Parking at any time in an illegal spot will result in arrest.   That's how laws and statutes work.  If a repeated parking were necessary to trigger the arrest, the number of repetitions would be stated.  Context and convention cannot be ignored or overlooked.

Comment: The meaning of (1) defaults to a semelfactive (one-time) meaning, though an 'even once' would really clarify. The Gricean maxim of manner (submaxim 'disambiguate where necessary) requires specifying context ('regularly/habitually/ ... parking') for the iterative reading. The same applies if the relative clause ('who parks ...' is chosen instead. / As you say, the iterative reading is forced in (2) / (3) is looking primarily at a one-off scenario; again a 'regularly' is needed to shift from this default. But I'd say the sentence would then be a little strange without an 'is likely to' etc.

Comment: If it wasn't text on an instructional sign but merely an observation, then "A person parking a car in an illegal place will be arrested." would probably be taken as describing a typical or usual case of affairs, not necessarily something that happens all the time. Similarly if I remarked after watching a crime movie "People who rob banks end up in jail", that would be a general statement about what typically happens - although a politician or judge might say it with the intention of it being a universal truth.

Comment: The sign doesn't imply either (A) or (B), which are both possible interpretations of the sign by a reader. Addressees know what context they're in; writers rarely do, so addressees' interpretations (i.e, pragmatics) takes precedence over authors' intentions (i.e, grammar).

Comment: @JohnLawler  Tell that to the judge.

Comment: Consider **No swimming**.   To ask whether that sign forbids swimming on multiple occasions but allows swimming on single occasions ignores the *ongoing/continuous* aspect and focuses only on the *habitual* aspect of the -ing form.  The *activity* is forbidden. So it doesn't matter if it's a one-off or you're a repeat offender. All swimming is forbidden.

Comment: Where is this draconian state where they arrest people for parking violations, rather than just making them pay a fine and possibly towing the car?

Comment: Is your question whether the participial phrase is equivalent to "who is parking" or "who parks"? Or is your question about whether "who parks" would have a habitual interpretation? I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you're asking.

Comment: What made you think there might be any doubt there? Further, what made you Post those examples without running them by your spelling checker?